# Is there an angular animate way to emulate this ng-class behaviour

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, ng-animate

I tried to use ng-animate i included in my controller 
app = angular.module('Packs', ['ngAnimate']);
This is my style:

```
<style>
    .animate-in {
        opacity: 0;
        max-height: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
        -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
        transition: all 0.5s;
    }
    .animate-out{
        opacity: 1;
        max-height: 200px;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
        -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
        transition: all 0.5s;
    }
</style>
```

This is the html that is not working, well, it does work, just i had to do it toggling classes manually, i wanted to use ng-animate

```
<div ng-click="toggle('pack1')">
    <div class="text" 
        ng-class="{'animate-in' : !displays.pack1,
               'animate-out' : displays.pack1}">
                            Some text to toggle
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So what is your issue? What do you mean by manually? What did you expect to happen and what actually did?

Comment: it has an accordion effect, but i couldnt get it to work in this way 
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf#animations

Comment: So maybe im missing something, when i toggle pack1 from false to true, ng-class animate toggles from animate-in to animate-out, and i get a good effect, but what i really wanted to do was to use ng-if="pack1" and animate="classname", but for some reason i spent an hour and couldnt make it. im using angular 1.2.x btw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use `ng-show = "displays.pack1"` on your text and then use the special classes `ng-hide`/`ng-hide-active`, see example [in the documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow)

Here is a jsfiddle that shows a toggle with opacity and height: http://jsfiddle.net/1djeqjfm/1/

```
.box.ng-hide { opacity:0; }
.box.ng-hide-active { opacity:1; }
```

(Or use `ng-if` and its classes `ng-enter`/`ng-leave`)